# Vim: How to enable hints in command bar

Tags: vimrc, gvim

I have Vim in Ubuntu and also gVim in Windows. The point is that gVim displays hints in the command bar (command-line under the statusline) but Vim does not. I mean hints that appears in bottom right corner while using “multi-character” commands like yanking selected text to clipboard. For example, in visual mode, I have some text selected and press `quote`, `plus`, and `y`. While doing this, I can see the following in the command bar (after `plus` but before `y`): [command-bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48MC6.png).

Unfortunately, it works out of the box in my gVim for Windows only. How can I configure the same behavior for Vim in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `set showcmd` to your config.

`:help showcmd`:

```
'showcmd' 'sc'      boolean (Vim default: on, Vi default: off)
            global
    Show (partial) command in the last line of the screen.  Set this
    option off if your terminal is slow.
    In Visual mode the size of the selected area is shown:
    - When selecting characters within a line, the number of characters.
      If the number of bytes is different it is also displayed: "2-6"
      means two characters and six bytes.
    - When selecting more than one line, the number of lines.
    - When selecting a block, the size in screen characters:
      {lines}x{columns}.
```